# How to install pip for python2 and pip3 for python3 in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python3, pip, python-2.7

How can I install `pip` for `python2` and `pip3` for `python3`. So that when I run `pip --version` it should show `pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)` and when I run `pip3 --version`, it should show `pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? The versions of Ubuntu which used python2 have reached end of life (also, support for python 2 ended at the beginning of 2020). The oldest supported version of Ubuntu is 20.04, which has python 3.8

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I have installed python2 and python-pip. When I do run the command ```pip2 --version```, I got ```pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)``` is shown. But when I install ```python3-pip```, it is removing ```python-pip```. How can I keep ```python-pip``` and install ```python3-pip```?

Comment: Do you really need python2 for something? It is unsupported.